# Selenium for Python wait conditions for elements with dynamic content

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to help a friend with some script to automatically bill insurances on some website they use for billing. I'm using Selenium  Webdriver and Python. The process requires picking options from drop-down menus, many of which are created when the page is loaded, but populated based on the selection the user makes in other fields.

I think that this dynamic population of the fields is the reason why the code crashes, even if I write something like:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'an_ID'))).click()
```

I get the error:

```
Exception has occurred: StaleElementReferenceException
Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

But if I step through the code line by line in debug mode, everything runs fine (I'm stepping through slowly enough that everything loads properly). That makes me think that the element is there early on and satisfied the wait condition, but the content is not there yet or something like that.

I can fix the problem by forcing the code to wait, e.g., with `time.sleep(2)`, but I literally have to do it for each element and that just seems wrong for all sorts of reasons, from code readability, to run-time, etc.

So all in all I select an item for a drop-down menu as:

```
def select_dropdown(self, locator, text, longer_wait=1):
   field = WebDriverWait(self.wd,self.wait).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,locator)))
   field.click()
   time.sleep(self.short_wait)
   field.send_keys(text)
   time.sleep(self.short_wait * longer_wait) # Some menus take longer to load
   field.send_keys('\ue007') # Send enter after item was highlighted
   time.sleep(self.short_wait)
```

Ugly, but removing any of sleep causes crashes.

Looking for ids for the elements in the content also doesn't seem like it would work, because the content is dynamic and I'm not sure the IDs can be expected to be the same across sessions.

I'm new to Selenium so I wonder if there's a more proper way.
I'm also happy to do some self-help reading some advanced tutorials/books on Selenium if you folks have good recommendations (I can only find basic ones).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your statement

> That makes me think that the element is there early on and satisfied the wait condition, but the content is not there yet or something like that.

is likely exactly right. Because you are choosing a selection from a dropdown which causes the page reload, it's likely that your wait condition is met but in the middle of performing an operation, the element reference goes stale.

There is a simple way to fix this. You need to wait for a selected element to go stale after an action that reloads the page. The steps are:

1. Get and store a reference (e.g. `button`) to the element you are going to click that will change/reload the page
2. Click `button`
3. Wait for `button` to become stale using `EC.staleness_of(button)` indicating that the page has started reloading
4. Continue the script

You'll basically repeat this process each time you're going to do some action that changes/updates the page.

Here's some sample code

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'an_ID'))); # store the reference to the element we're about to click
button.click() # this click reloads/changes the page
wait.until(EC.staleness_of(button)) # wait for the reference to go stale
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'some_other_ID'))).click();
# proceed with the rest of the script
```

---

NOTE: Per the docs, you should not mix implicit and explicit (`WebDriverWait`) waits. You should remove the implicit wait and just reuse the `WebDriverWait` whenever you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I quickly tried your suggestion with no success, but I'm not sure I implemented it correctly for my use case--I'll try more next weekend.
Just to be sure we are on the same page: I'm trying to select an item from a dropdown. The menu is an input field that I can type text in before all the options are loaded. The items of the menu change over time (they may add/remove/reorder them), so I select the item by sending its name so that the other options are removed, and then sending a return to make the selection. The staleness of the field itself times out.

Comment: I don't suppose you can provide a link to the page? I could almost assuredly figure it out once seeing the page itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. I could provide is a snippet of the html code of the page and my code. Would that be useful, or did you want to try to interact with the element to figure it out?

Comment: So the field is like a special dropdown? Like on the google search page where you start typing and the dropdown options change based on what you typed? I'm just trying to get a better sense of what you are trying to describe. Is there a page that you know of that has behavior similar to this private page?

Comment: Your provided code right now only shows a single click. Can you put more of the surrounding code that you think is involved with the issue? Sounds like you are finding an element, using .`send_keys()`, and then ? and you get the stale element exception. Once you post a little more code, I'll come back and review it and update my answer. I think I have an idea but I want to see your code first so I can update your code instead of adding more sample code that you then have to adapt.

Comment: Hi JeffC, sorry for the delay--I only have time to work on this over the weekend.

The field is a dropdown menu. If you were to use the page yourself, you'd click on it, it would start loading the options (which don't seem to be available as soon as the page loads), you'd start typing the name of the option you want, wait for the corresponding item to be highlighted, and then you'd click on it (or press enter).

It would be easier if I could just select by the id of the element in the list, but they can change over time.

Comment: I see the updated code but you didn't mark where the stale element exception is being thrown.

Comment: I added to the main question the code I use to select an item in the drop-down menu. I can try to get some of the HTML code if that would help.